# Send data from large form by AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, smarty

I have a form with 30 field: 3 field which are 10 times repeated. This is my code:

```
<form id="artikelform" method="POST" name="controleartikelen" action="">
<table id="controle">
    <tr><th>Maakartikel</th><th>Aantal</th><th>Leverdatum</th></tr>
    {for $i=1 to 10}
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="artikel" class="artinput"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="aantal" class="aantalinput"/>&nbsp;x</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="datum" class="dateinput"/></td>
        </tr>
    {/for}
</table>
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:startControle();" value="Controleer"/>
</form>
```

I want to send my form-values to a PHP script by AJAX (POST-method). I tried to send `$.param($("#artikelform").serializeArray());` with my ajax as POST-data but the result of that function is not usable (just a lot of variables in a sort of GET-format). What is the best way to use this form in combination with AJAX? Maybe another way of using `serializeArray()`?

EDIT:

this is my code for the AJAX-request:

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'myscript.php',
            cache: false,
            data: formdata,
            type: "POST"
        }).done(function(data){
            $("#resultwrapper").html(data);
        })
```

Comment: Just use `$(form).serialize()` (which is the same as `$.param($(form).serializeArray())`), it'll get passed to php just fine.

Comment: ok, what should be the right PHP-code to get the first value of 'artikel' then?

Comment: var dump $_POST rather than guessing, maybe that'll help you see what the structure that passing form fields in that way generates.

Comment: var_dump($_POST['artikel']) returns string(0) "" , unless I add [] to my inputnames

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either:

1) use the PHP function json_decode() to map the JSON encoded data structure to a PHP array, or

2) don't serialize the payload but name the variables as php arrays thus:

```
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="artikel[]" class="artinput"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="aantal[]" class="aantalinput"/>&nbsp;x</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="datum[]" class="dateinput"/></td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try `$('#artikelform').serialize()` rather than `$.param($("#artikelform").serializeArray());` you should then be able to access your fields in your php script with `$_POST['fieldname']` without a problem

Comment: nope, var_dump($_POST['artikel']) returns string(0) "" , unless I add [] to my inputnames